# Form validation error. Form is allowing empty fields?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, validation, loops

I have a simple contact form with name, email , number and message. 
I've used javascript to validate it and give feedback.  All other functions work perfectly, turning the input boxes red if they contain invalid characters or values. However when I perform a presence check on all the boxes, the form submits even if only one of the inputs has a value in it.

here is my jS...

```
function submit_it() {


    var name = document.getElementById("username");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var num = document.getElementById("racenum");
    var messagecontent = document.getElementById("messagecontent");

    var inputs = []; 
    inputs[0] = name; 
    inputs[1] = email;
    inputs[2] = num;
    inputs[3] = messagecontent;

    for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)  // Loop through input elements.
    {
        // Perform presence check.
        if(inputs[i].value=="" || messagecontent.value == 'null') //If check fails
        {
            alert("There are errors in your message form."); // Error
            name.focus(); // Return cursor to first input element.
            break; 
            return;
        }
        else  // If Presence check passes
        {
         $.post("sndmsg.php", { com: "" , pg: ""});
            alert("Your message has been sent."); 
            for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
            {
                inputs[i].value = '';
                inputs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
            }
            break; 
            console.log(logit);
            return;

        }
    }

}
```

I'm assuming it's a problem with the loop or the If statement but I can't figure out why it's not picking up the error!
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: in your  if(inputs[i].value=="" || messagecontent.value == 'null') condition can you once  try commenting break; statement and check

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

and in your code do this:

```
var val = inputs[i].value;

if(val.trim() == "" || messagecontent.value == 'null'){// stuff}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is flawed. You are actually trying to POST the form once for each field that is correctly filled..  Also you will never reach the return statements as the break statement will exit the for loop at that point.

You should move the POST call **after** completion of the for loop, and make sure to only call it if all field were correctly filled. Something structured like this (pseudocode):

```
for...
{
    if field check fails
    {
        alert, highlight whetever
        return;     // return from whole function
    }
}

// we come here only if all fields checked ok
post data
```